# issue, when scan few barcodes one byone

Tags: android, firemonkey, barcode

I have a problem with my android applicationon PDA device 
I made an simple application (Firemonkey, only Memo on Form) and want to scan barcodes with buit-in barcode scanner.

On memoKeyUp event I wait for Enter character

```
 if (Key = vkReturn)  then
    begin
      some code ....
    end;
```

Problem is if I scan 3 or 4 barcodes and all is fine, but suddenly my code is not executed. It is look like enter character is not came from scanner?
And when I scan again my code is executed twice!

I know you are not clairvoyants, but maybe someone has any idea what I can check or read barcode characters other way.

Comment: you are using datawedge from motorola ? If yes, please try to use receiver instead of keystroke (simply disable keystroke and register your intent action in datawedge). Search how to implement receiver in firemonkey app (JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)

Comment: Are you sure that Delphi has built-in barcode scanner? It have no. What bar code scanner are you using (name)?